# CPU Usage test on Visual Studio 2013 Pro Update 2

Tags: c#, performance, visual-studio-2013, diagnostics

I am trying to find out why my program is running slow. I've tried to use CPU sampling (from suggested by "Performance Wizard"), but it gave me only most often used functions but not the timings of which my app's part is the slowest. After some search I've found this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/02/28/new-cpu-usage-tool-in-the-performance-and-diagnostics-hub-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx), what would be nice and dandy if not one fact: when I'm trying to start CPU usage test VS is telling me that project I would like to test (ddl project) cannot be tested because tool "does not support selected project".

---

Project (in C#) is created with default parameters and dealing with MS SQL DB via LinqToSql class.
All solution is in pure C#.

---

So, my question would be, what are the criteria to run CPU usage or/and others test in Performance and Diagnostics tool?

Comment: You cannot profile a dll. Start or create an executable that utilized the suspected slow code and profile it.

Comment: but the CPU ptofiler doesint enable even when actual starup project (exe) is selected.